# Metamask error - Denying load of chrome extension

Tags: metamask

I receive this error when trying to send ETH to my smart contract for tokens.

I am able to whitelist Account 1 but when trying to buy tokens with my 2nd Account or whitelist the 2nd Account this error shows.

Denying load of chrome extension - Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.

Error is found in google chrome console

```
inpage.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscription' of undefined
    at t.exports.data (index.js:105)
    at u (inpage.js:1)
    at t.exports.a.emit (inpage.js:1)
    at a.<anonymous> (inpage.js:1)
    at u (inpage.js:1)
    at a.emit (inpage.js:1)
    at inpage.js:1
    at l.write [as _write] (inpage.js:1)
    at b (inpage.js:1)
    at inpage.js:1
    at l.v.write (inpage.js:1)
    at a.y (inpage.js:1)
    at h (inpage.js:1)
    at a.s.emit (inpage.js:1)
    at _ (inpage.js:1)
    at w (inpage.js:1)
    at a.b.push (inpage.js:1)
    at t.exports._write (inpage.js:1)
    at b (inpage.js:1)
    at inpage.js:1
    at t.exports.v.write (inpage.js:1)
    at o.y (inpage.js:1)
    at h (inpage.js:1)
    at o.s.emit (inpage.js:1)
    at _ (inpage.js:1)
    at w (inpage.js:1)
    at o.b.push (inpage.js:1)
    at o._onMessage (inpage.js:1)
data @ index.js:105
u @ inpage.js:1
a.emit @ inpage.js:1
(anonymous) @ inpage.js:1
u @ inpage.js:1
a.emit @ inpage.js:1
(anonymous) @ inpage.js:1
write @ inpage.js:1
b @ inpage.js:1
(anonymous) @ inpage.js:1
v.write @ inpage.js:1
y @ inpage.js:1
h @ inpage.js:1
s.emit @ inpage.js:1
_ @ inpage.js:1
w @ inpage.js:1
b.push @ inpage.js:1
_write @ inpage.js:1
b @ inpage.js:1
(anonymous) @ inpage.js:1
v.write @ inpage.js:1
y @ inpage.js:1
h @ inpage.js:1
s.emit @ inpage.js:1
_ @ inpage.js:1
w @ inpage.js:1
b.push @ inpage.js:1
o._onMessage @ inpage.js:1
setTimeout (async)
u @ inpage.js:1
a.emit @ inpage.js:1
(anonymous) @ inpage.js:1
u @ inpage.js:1
a.emit @ inpage.js:1
(anonymous) @ inpage.js:1
write @ inpage.js:1
b @ inpage.js:1
(anonymous) @ inpage.js:1
v.write @ inpage.js:1
y @ inpage.js:1
h @ inpage.js:1
s.emit @ inpage.js:1
_ @ inpage.js:1
w @ inpage.js:1
b.push @ inpage.js:1
_write @ inpage.js:1
b @ inpage.js:1
(anonymous) @ inpage.js:1
v.write @ inpage.js:1
y @ inpage.js:1
h @ inpage.js:1
s.emit @ inpage.js:1
_ @ inpage.js:1
w @ inpage.js:1
b.push @ inpage.js:1
o._onMessage @ inpage.js:1
postMessage (async)
o._write @ contentscript.js:1
b @ contentscript.js:1
(anonymous) @ contentscript.js:1
v.write @ contentscript.js:1
y @ contentscript.js:1
h @ contentscript.js:1
s.emit @ contentscript.js:1
_ @ contentscript.js:1
w @ contentscript.js:1
b.push @ contentscript.js:1
_write @ contentscript.js:1
b @ contentscript.js:1
(anonymous) @ contentscript.js:1
v.write @ contentscript.js:1
y @ contentscript.js:1
h @ contentscript.js:1
s.emit @ contentscript.js:1
_ @ contentscript.js:1
w @ contentscript.js:1
b.push @ contentscript.js:1
_write @ contentscript.js:1
b @ contentscript.js:1
(anonymous) @ contentscript.js:1
v.write @ contentscript.js:1
y @ contentscript.js:1
h @ contentscript.js:1
s.emit @ contentscript.js:1
_ @ contentscript.js:1
w @ contentscript.js:1
b.push @ contentscript.js:1
o._onMessage @ contentscript.js:1
localhost/:1 Denying load of chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/sourcemaps/inpage.js.map. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.
index.js:1 GET chrome-extension://invalid/ net::ERR_FAILED
```

[image: Console Image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug introduced in the v8 version of Metamask, related to the "accountsChanged" event.
They have fixed this error and it should be resolved in the next release.

Here is the link to the closed issue on their github : https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/9013 .

Comment: Thank you for this. I will look up how to downgrade to v.7.78 seeing as someone in that thread said it worked there. I guess I'll have to wait until the next version is released.

Comment: any chance you know how to downgrade to an earlier version of metamask? I haven't been able to find any good info on that.

Comment: First choose your version from the releases page : https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/releases . Then you can follow this tuto : https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015489471-How-to-Install-MetaMask-Manually .

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just updated my version of web3 to `"web3": "^1.3.5"` and it started to work!